# svg: Open (a xlink:href) another svg image in current frame - cross browser nightmare?

Tags: svg, xlink

I have been bashing my head against this problem for awhile now and I was hoping for some help/advice.

I have an svg graphic which I have embedded into an iframe (icky I know, but we have created our own dashboard/widget application, and this was the easiest way to port our existing svg framework into the widget).  I need to be able to have those svg graphics link to other svg graphics, and I need them to open in the same iframe, which at the moment is driving me mad.

I found this post which talks about methods of [linking in svg](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/a-element.html), however, the comparison at the bottom seems to indicate that it is *impossible* in IE (7 at least) to have a link open in anything but the "current window".  This seems to be the case in everything I have tried, but was hoping that somewhere out there in internet-land, someone has found a work around for this.

**Here is what I've tried:**

```
1. <a xlink:href='<path to new embedded graphic>' target='<iframeName>' ... />
```

**Chrome 13:** Works perfect, opens in correct frame!
**Firefox 6.0.2:** Attempts to open in a new tab 
**IE 9.0.8:** Attempts to open in a new tab

```
2. <a xlink:href='<path to new embedded graphic>' xlink:show='replace' ... />
```

**Chrome 13:** Replaces the svg graphic with my desired file, however, since I am replacing with an ASP page that contains the embedded svg graphic, I end up getting a 'nested' effect on my page.
**Firefox 6.0.2:** Similar to Chrome - loads in place but nesting occurs, although in FF the graphic does not even load.
**IE 9.0.8:** Similar to Chrome, loads in place but nesting occurs.

It seems as if setting the target frame is the way I want to go, but is there anyway to make it work in FF and IE?  Has anyone been successful with this?

The other thing I am attempting to try is setting the frame's window.document.location.href in javascript when the link is clicked. It's proving tricky to do though, and I have really only been attempting in Chrome.  I was hoping for some advice before I wasted too much time on it.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the following worked just fine for me in IE9, Chrome 13 and FF 6:

```
<a xlink:href='<path to new embedded graphic>' target='_parent' .../>
```

This opens up the graphic in the parent window, which happens to be my iFrame.